# Trouble in printing length of this list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to print the length of this list, but whenever I'm trying to print the output is 1. The compiler is treating whole list as single element. So how can I get length of this list?

```py
import random
names_string = input("Give me everybody's names, separated by a comma. ")
names = names_string.split(", ")
print(len(names))
```

This displays

```
Give me everybody's names, separated by a comma. Yo,Gh,Kl
1
```

Comment: Please post the actual code, not an image. Makes it alot easier to help you if we can copy-paste the code :)

Comment: @UzumakiPanda, if you feel that one of the answers has conclusively answered your question, you may select it as **the** answer by clicking the check mark next to it.  Doing so will grant you 2 reputation.

Answer (score 3):

Your input text is separated by commas with no spaces.  However, your code splits on `', '`, a comma followed by a space.  Whenever you split on a string which doesn't occur in the input string, the result is a list containing just the input string.

Therefore, you should do `names_string.split(',')`.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are splitting the `names_string` by `,`  which if you look carefully includes a comma AND a space, but when you input your data "Yo,Gh,Kl" you didn't include spaces after the commas. When `split()` was called, no instances of `,`  were found.